# Как избежать смартскрин безплатно

Tags: c++

Как этого избежать без отключения самого смартскрина? или что вообще делать? Помогите пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> fill(int size, bool fromNull = true)
{
    std::vector<int> vect;
    if (fromNull)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++)
        {
            vect.push_back(i);
            std::cout << vect.at(i) << "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int element = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++)
        {
            vect.push_back(element);
            std::cout << vect.at(i) << "\n";
   

     element++;
    }
}
return vect;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vect = fill(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Допустим, я написал этот код. Скомпилировал в екзешник(.exe) и отправил другу. Так как я нелицензированый кодер то у друга вылезет смартскрин.

Comment: возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555648/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: он закрыт. вы можете туда ответить?

Comment: Даже платно — никак, потому что санкции

Comment: я в Украине....

Comment: Уже давно есть такая проблема. На [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/articles/505194/) неплохо о ней рассказали.

Comment: "он закрыт" — ну так сделайте правку вопроса и нажмите галочку "устраняет первоначальную причину закрытия".

Comment: Ну в Украине тогда покупайте сертификат разработчика, наверное

Comment: спасибо to everyone

Comment: @mironmeow напиши это плз в ответе?

Comment: В такой ситуации наверное будет проще другу разрешать запуск приложения, когда он получает предупреждение от самртскрина.